# twitter bootstrap modal disappears by pressing button

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I´ve created a window modal using twitter bootstrap, but when I press the delete button the window modal disappears

My code for the windows modal:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="box-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">{% block modal_title %}<!-- Aqui va el titulo de la pagina modal --> {% endblock %}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="alert hidden" id="modal-alert"></div>
 <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#box-modal" name="delete-productCart" value="2" id="delete-productCart" class="btn btn-danger">               

    </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            {% block modal_footer %}
                            <!-- Aquí va el pie de la pagina modal -->
                            {% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I click the button the window modal disappears

```
   $("#box-modal").on("shown",function(event)
   {

       $("#delete-productCart").click(function()
       {
           alert("hi");
       });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try removing attributes

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#box-modal"
```

from the delete button. These are toggling the modal itself by default.
You can then manually toggle the modal by using:

```
$('#box-modal').modal('toggle')
```

Comment: Just add alert to this fiddle, ok?